# Disaggregate while adding column

Tags: r, aggregate, weighted

I have a df of aggregated test results:

```
   title                            attempts correct
   <chr>                               <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 abdominal mass, question 1            399    61.4
 2 abdominal mass, question 2            405    72.6
 3 achalasia, question 1                 156    85.9
 4 achalasia, question 2                 277    56.0
 5 achalasia, question 3                 326    87.7
```

To see which topics/questions were easier or harder (based on % correct column) while taking into account that some questions have been attempted many more times than others, the df can be disaggregated from the original 1,000 + rows into >200,000 rows as below. This means there is now one row for every attempt to answer each question.

```
df %>%  
  uncount(attempts)


# A tibble: 207,179 x 2
   title                      correct
   <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 2 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 3 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 4 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 5 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 6 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
 7 abdominal mass, question 1    61.4
```

Question 1 alone now has 399 rows, and since 61.4% of the time it was answered correctly, the desired output is:

An additional column, 'right_wrong'.

- The first 61.4% of 399 ~= 245 rows of question one would have 'right' in that column and the next 154 would have 'wrong'.
- 72.6% of the 405 rows of question 2 attempts would be labeled 'right', and so forth for each question of the 200K+ rows.

All this is likely unnecessary and there is probably an easier way to 'weight' the correct answers by number of attempts, but "dammit Jim, I'm a doctor not a statistician."

Answer (score 3):

An easier option would to do `uncount` after creating the 'yes/no' column of counts, reshape to 'long' format and then do `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df %>% 
   mutate(right = round(attempts * correct/100), 
   wrong = attempts - right) %>%
   select(-attempts, -correct) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -title, names_to = 'right_wrong') %>% 
   uncount(value)

count(out, title, right_wrong)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   title                      right_wrong     n
#   <chr>                      <chr>       <int>
# 1 abdominal mass, question 1 right         245
# 2 abdominal mass, question 1 wrong         154
# 3 abdominal mass, question 2 right         294
# 4 abdominal mass, question 2 wrong         111
# 5 achalasia, question 1      right         134
# 6 achalasia, question 1      wrong          22
# 7 achalasia, question 2      right         155
# 8 achalasia, question 2      wrong         122
# 9 achalasia, question 3      right         286
#10 achalasia, question 3      wrong          40
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(title = c("abdominal mass, question 1", 
"abdominal mass, question 2", 
"achalasia, question 1", "achalasia, question 2", "achalasia, question 3"
), attempts = c(399L, 405L, 156L, 277L, 326L), correct = c(61.4, 
72.6, 85.9, 56, 87.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```